# tomcat hide exception stack trace

Tags: tomcat

I am writing a Jersey app for file upload and download. I have 2 tomcat server s1 and s2. s1 is used to hide s2 from client. The procedure is client send request to s1, s1 send request to s2 and s2 handle the request.

For file download, s1 will send response upon the file is located in storage and then file start downloading through stream. In this case, when s2 is down while file downloading, s1 will get a confusion refused exception and this exception can't be caught by error-page so that the tomcat specified error page will be returned along with stack trace. How can I customize this error page?